# Add paramethers to libcurl GET in c++

Tags: c++, libcurl

I want to add some additional data in variable to HTTP GET using c++. When I make request using HTTP POST I do it like that:

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, path);
    curl_formadd(&beginPostList, &endPostList, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "variable1", CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, variable1.c_str(), CURLFORM_END);
    curl_formadd(&beginPostList, &endPostList, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "variable2", CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, variable2.c_str(), CURLFORM_END);
    curl_formadd(&beginPostList, &endPostList, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "variable3", CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, variable3.c_str(), CURLFORM_END);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, beginPostList);
```

But how can I do similar thing using GET methid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `GET` just append the parameters to the URL, like

```
http://some.host.com/some/path?variable1=value1&variable2=value2
```

I'm sure you've seen it before!

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to the same problem and although your way works, I was hoping that libcurl would offer something similar to other languages (e.g., pycurl) which has a way of feeding parameters separately so that the library could automatically handle 'clean up'. e.g., if I had field and the user put an & character, then taking the variable without modification could cause a problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ThinkBonobo If you're using C++ then put all parameters in a `std::map`, with the key being the "variable" name and the value being the values (as strings, or using e.g. [Boost Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html)). Then you can add and remove key-value pairs as much as you want. Use this map to construct the URL just before performing the actual GET operation.

Answer (score 1):

Some support of this now exist (since curl version 7.62). The `'?'` and `'&'` are added automatically but I currently see no way of adding the parameters and values separately so they still have to be created with a `'='` between them.

```
// Create URL
CURLUcode result;
CURLU *url = curl_url();
char *urlStr;

result = curl_url_set(url, CURLUPART_URL, "https://example.com/hello.json", 0);

if(!result) {
    const char paramValue1[] = "param1=value1";
    const char paramValue2[] = "param2=value2";

    // Add paramters
    result = curl_url_set(url, CURLUPART_QUERY, paramValue1, CURLU_APPENDQUERY);
    result = curl_url_set(url, CURLUPART_QUERY, paramValue2, CURLU_APPENDQUERY);

    // Convert URL to string for printing
    result = curl_url_get(url, CURLUPART_URL, &urlStr, 0);

    printf("New URL: %s", urlStr);
}
curl_url_cleanup(url);

// Output: New URL: https://example.com/hello.json?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

**References**

[1] https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_url_set.html