# How to retrieve table information using libcurl

Tags: c++, c++11, curl, libcurl

I am new to using the libcurl libraries in C++ just to learn some new stuff, however i cant seem to find to much useful info on the subject with good practical examples.

I am trying to retrieve some stats from this website:
http://www.squawka.com/football-player-rankings#performance-score#player-stats#spanish-la-liga|season-2014/2015#all-teams#all-player-positions#16#39#0#0#90#23/08/2014#28/12/2014#season#1#all-matches#total#desc#total

For this, after the proper includes i am pulling the webpage using:

```
int main()
{
    CURL *curl;                                                                                                                                      
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();                                                                                                                         
    if(curl)
    {
        // Set URL
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.squawka.com/football-player-rankings#performance-score#player-stats#spanish-la-liga|season-20
14/2015#r-madrid#all-player-positions#16#34#0#0#90#23/08/2014#14/11/2014#season#1#all-matches#total#desc#total");                                    

        // Perform the request, res will get the return code
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);                                                                                                               

        // Check for errors
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
        {                                                                                                                                            
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }                                                                                                                                            

        // Print the code
        cout << res << endl;                                                                                                                         

        // Always cleanup each call to curl_easy_init
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);                                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                                
    return 0;
}
```

From the websites source code i can check for example that the name Messi is in:

```
<div class="stats-player-name">Messi</div> in <tr style class="ranking-data-row" data-id="1569" data-row="1">.
```

However if i run a search on the printed code i can´t see the name Messi, nor his stats anywhere. What am i missing so i can tell the site to download all the players data? Shouldnt this be done automatically when i give the URL?

I tried using something like this: [Add paramethers to libcurl GET in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582838/add-paramethers-to-libcurl-get-in-c/19582883#19582883) with no success.

Thanks in advance for some basic guidelines so i can continue with this.

Comment: Where do you see the name Messi? There is no such string in the page source code.

Comment: The page in question is using client-side scripting to populate the table dynamically. So you won't be able to parse this particular page's HTML to get the stats, because they are not in the HTML to begin with. You will have to decipher the script's code and figure out where it is pulling its table data from, and then change your code to retrieve that data instead.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in my message, Messi appears in the stats-player-name class.
I´ll check Remy´s feedback and do as he suggested even if it doesn´t look like an easy solution for a beginner :)